# Socket.io - Receiving data every 34 milliseconds

Tags: c#, javascript, canvas, live-streaming

I'm attempting to create a HTML5 'remote desktop' using images captured from a C# app. The images are are converted into base64 strings and sent via socket.io to the page and displayed on the canvas. It works pretty well on my PC, but on any slower computer it doesn't. It can't seem to update fast enough and causes the page to crash. Here's the 'receive' action code:

```
socket.of('/1').on('receive', function (data) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, example.width, example.height);
    };

    img.src = "data:image/png;base64," + data.message;
});
```

The data is sent every 34 milliseconds so the canvas updates at around 29 fps and appears to be a live video. Is there a way I can receive the data and draw the image in another "thread"? Or can anyone suggest how to fix this issue? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps the browser is crashing because the next packet comes in before it has finished rendering the first one. Try skipping packets that come in between the time you receive a packet and the time that the drawImage call completes.

Comment: Why is it a new Image each frame? Also: there's a reason most video codecs don't send full frames each frame...

Comment: Hey. @JonBenedicto I don't think it's that because even if comment out the lines above but leave the event, it'll still lag and crash. Thanks though.

Comment: @MarcGravell How do the video codecs do it? Send half a frame each time and combine them? What do you suggest?

Comment: @Joey video encodings usually work in terms of clever deltas from the existing frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browserling](http://www.browserling.com) does exactly what you're trying to accomplish – it displays a remote desktop interface using `<canvas>`.  Conveniently, they've left [their code](http://browserling.com/bundle/encoder.js) unminified.  You you could take a look at how they're doing it.

If you can set your C# end up as a [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) server, I'd use [noVNC](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC), a browser VNC client that uses WebSockets and `<canvas>`.  (Worth reading are noVNC's [performance notes](https://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/wiki/Performance-notes).)

Comment: Thanks josh. I'll have a look at the code and see if I can get anything from it.

Answer (score 0):

While you are using socket.io that allows to do cross-communication and send data from client to server any time same as server to client, you should make mechanics to not just spam client with data, but to be a little bit more careful.

When you send image data to client, do not send another straight away. First of all ping can be low is one thing, but bandwidth can be low - is another thing.
When you send image data from server to client, then client receives data, make client to send automatically to server information that you received data and processed it, making server aware that client is ready to receive next image.

You FPS will be dropped, but this is common practice to make realtime video working efficient on any type of connection and with any type of resolutions.
This is not playing video that already exists - so there is no place for buffering or pre caching processes.
To slightly increase performance, you can calculate based on ping and reaction speed for receiving and processing image to send next frame a bit earlier, it might increase FPS by 5-10 on good connection and 0-3 on slow ones.

In meantime, you might want to have a look into better way of streaming realtime images, like MJPEG (Motiona JPEG), that allows to stream realtime image, but to go away from websockets, because using WebSockets for image streaming it creates extra layer of processing to satisfy protocols specifics. While MJPEG is meant to be used for image streaming.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, you may have found a solution since.

If not, you can have a look to [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille), an HTML4/5 browser based remote desktop client. it uses C#, websockets, canvas and base64 enncoded images (PNG, JPEG or WEBP, depending on configuration and bandwidth).

A few years ago, HTML5 browsers weren't able to cope with a large websocket traffic, so I tried to setup 2 websockets: one for the uplink and another downlink. It helped a bit but wasn't very satisfying. Si I tried to throttle the websocket, having a client side packet receive ack before sending the next one. It was better on some browsers, but induced a slowdown on others.

Nowadays browsers don't need such throttling; Myrtille simply push the images to the browser as they come.

That said, the RDP protocol is smart enough to process and send only the difference between two frames (regions), like most video codecs, instead of the whole display.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the UI / DOM is being updated, changed, altered or anything to do with changing the viewport the browser will lock up during this time.

Right now what you're trying to do is almost impossible, and the only reason I did not say impossible is because you never know now days ;).

I am a c# developer as well and I am so biting at the bit for the changes that will be here for us by next year this time.

You'r about a year to early...

Comment: This doesn't really constructively answer the question.

Comment: No, you cannot achieve this type of operation. Retrieving data from the server and updating it fast enough to simulate a picture movie or moving pictures purely using today's browsers and JavaScript as the client.

Comment: [False.](http://www.browserling.com/) -- *"We run the browsers on our servers.  Fully interactive sessions, not static screenshots.  No flash, no applets, nothing to install. Powered entirely by `<canvas>` and javascript."*

Comment: I am very curious now to see something like this in action. Have you got a link? To stream data from a server and display it onto some client browser with-out a plug-in, using the new html5 canvas, and for the viewing on the client to be viewed as a remote desktop sounds attractive. Got a link?

Comment: As I [mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10919691/201952), [Browserling](http://www.browserling.com/) does this.  Head over there and [plug in a URL to give it a try](http://browserling.com/encoder.html#uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&browser=explorer%2F9.0).

Comment: I'll have to disagree on this one. It just isn't there yet.